# In Windows 10 native webcam app, how to disable the square that follows the face?

Tags: windows-10

I can't find any option for this particular feature. It's a Microsoft product too so I don't expect too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-camera-winpc/how-do-you-disable-face-detection-on-the-windows/8ad07ecb-3333-46f6-b461-bf11a3ddf373?auth=1) an option to disable facerecognition is not implemented yet.

> However, we have yet to include the option to turn off Facial Recognition feature in Windows 10 Camera app. We suggest that you submit a suggestion to our Feedback Hub.

Comment: I went ahead and quoted the relevant information for you.  In the future, please do that yourself, we expect that from quality answers

Answer (score 1):

The face-following square only appears in camera mode, as opposed to video mode.  So you can get rid of it by switching to video mode by clicking the video button on the right side of the window that looks like this:

```
  +---------+ +
  |         |/|
  |         | |
  |         |\|
  +---------+ +
```

That doesn't actually start *recording* anything, it just prepares to do so (rather than taking single pictures).

More information about using the camera app is at [How to use the Camera app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-use-the-camera-app-ea40b69f-be6a-840e-9c8c-1fd6eea97c22), but it doesn't mention the detail about the face-following square.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).